# WPF: How can I have controls in a grid automatically resize when the grid is resized?

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I'm very new to WPF: I need to have buttons on a grid resize as the form is resized. The spaces between the buttons also need to stay constant. Is there some property that I can set? I played around with width/height as auto, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) property of button. then the spaces between the button would be fix.